# Tritium - Phosphorescense Illumination

Tags: optics

In a tritium phosphor light, such as a tritium gun site, the tritium activates the phosphor with an ejected electron. What happens to that ejected electron after being captured by the phosphor material. How is the phosphor changed.

Comment: How much detail do you want? FWIW, the [Wikipedia article on phosphors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphor#Radioluminescence) is rather extensive, but I suppose that its explanation of how phosphors work is a bit terse, and assumes some knowledge of the theory of solid state electronics. It gives brief descriptions of how various phosphors are degraded through use.

Comment: That was a good source. Thankyou.

Comment: No worries. And if you're wondering about the eventual fate of the ejected electron, it's likely to get captured by a He-3 ion (which was created by a tritium atom decaying) but it needs to surrender most of its kinetic energy first.